# aws cloudformation stack not responding when redeploying from visual studio toolkit 2012

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

I am using the latest version of AWS toolkit for visual studio to publish my MVC5 project to AWS CloudFormation. I can create a new stack and publish but I can publish to stack created a few days ago. When I try to do that visual studio just hangs. I have confirmed that I have rights because I can publish a new stack. Any thoughts ?

Comment: what's the status of the stack ?

Comment: What do you mean by the status of the stack it says CREATE_COMPLETE is that what you've asked for ?

Answer (score 1):

Just posting the answer so it would help someone in the future. It turns out in ec2 windows instances, if you reboot the machine and then try to deploy the service called "Web Management Service" is stopped. Once I manually restart the service it was possible to deploy using AWS deploy.